# Intensity of EM waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

For a mechanical wave, the energy transported  is directly proportional to the square of its amplitude.

In quantum physics, the energy of a photon is proportional to its frequency.

Will changing the frequency of light also affect its intensity?

Comment: maybe this link will interest you  https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends. For a general electromagnetic wave, there is no specific relation between the two. You can have a low-intensity, high-frequency wave (which has only a few photons), a high-intensity, high-frequency wave (which has more photons), a low-intensity, low-frequency wave (which has a large number of photons), or a high-intensity, low-frequency wave (which has an even larger number of photons). Any relation between frequency and intensity is determined by the specific details of whatever device is producing your electromagnetic radiation.